GSAP Vertical Card Scroll on ScrollTrigger
I am new to GSAP.
The issue is I want to try a ScrollTrigger in a section and I have some cards placed vertically in that section, so here is the animation I want to achieve:

All cards scale and opacity are set to scale: 0.7, opacity: 0.6 only the first card is set to scale: 1, opacity: 1.
So when the Section is scrolled, the First Card Scale will scale down to scale: 0.7 and opacity opacity: 0.6; this is the first animation.
When the first card animation is happing the second animation should start which is the next card will scale up to scale: 1 and opacity opacity: 1
Then the next card which is the third one should start the second animation and the previous card which is card no. 2, should start the first animation which is scaled down and opacity down
Also there is SVG path that looks like the groove should follow only the active card and the active card is the card that has scale: 1, opacity: 1

So these are the three animations I want to achieve, I have tried different approaches which I have commented on in my code.
Here is my CodePen.
This is my attempted code for now:


const cards = gsap.utils.toArray(".card");
const spacer = 40;
const minScale = 0.7;

const distributor = gsap.utils.distribute({
  base: minScale,
  amount: 0.2,
  grid: "atuo",
  axis: "y"
});

cards.forEach((card, index) => {

  const scaleVal = distributor(index, cards[index], cards);

  const tween_one = gsap.to(card, {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: card,
      start: `top-=${index * spacer} top`,
      scrub: true,
      markers: true,
      invalidateOnRefresh: true
    },
    ease: "none",
    scale: scaleVal,
    opacity: 0.6
  });


  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: card,
    start: `top-=${index * spacer} top`,
    endTrigger: '.card_container',
    end: `bottom top+=${200 + (cards.length * spacer)}`,
    // pin: true,
    // pinSpacing: false,
    markers: true,
    id: 'pin',
    invalidateOnRefresh: true,
  });




});
body {
  background: #212529;
}

.cards_section {
  padding: 100px 50px;
}

.card_container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
}

.indicator_left_wraper {
  width: 4%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 16px 0 0 0;
}

.right_wraper {
  width: 96%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.card {
  transform: scale(0.7);
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.card.card_active {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.card_title {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.card_title h1,
.card_title p,
.card_content h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
}

.card_title h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #F37A53;
  padding: 0 0 24px 0;
}

.card_title h1 span,
.card_title p {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #f3f3f3;
}

.card_title p {
  padding: 0 0 14px 0;
}

.card_content {
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.card_content h3 {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

.card_key_points {
  border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

.card_key_points ul li {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 12px 0 0 0;
}

.left_border_line {
  height: 100vh;
}

.left_indicator_svg {
  margin: 0 0 0 -24px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/x-icon"
      href="/assets/logo/ak_logo_doblue_stroke_circle_ungrouped.svg"
    />

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- UiKit CDN -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.17.0/dist/css/uikit.min.css"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

    <title>Vetical Cards</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<section class="cards_section">

  <div class="card_wraper">

    <div class="card_container">

      <div class="indicator_left_wraper">

        <svg width="1" height="1513" viewBox="0 0 1 1513" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path class="exper_line" d="M0.5 1V1512" stroke="#4CBBDC" stroke-linecap="round" />
        </svg>

        <svg class="left_indicator_svg" width="31" height="382" viewBox="0 0 31 382" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M0.802537 48.2198L24 8V382L0 351.92V51.2175C0 50.1652 0.276771 49.1314 0.802537 48.2198Z" fill="#4CBBDC" />
          <path d="M1.80427 48.1631L25 8L24.4783 381L1 351.46V51.1639C1 50.1103 1.27739 49.0754 1.80427 48.1631Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_551_5)" />
          <g filter="url(#filter0_dddd_551_5)">
            <circle cx="23.5" cy="7.5" r="6.5" fill="#4CBBDC" />
          </g>
          <defs>
            <filter id="filter0_dddd_551_5" x="16" y="0" width="15" height="17" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
              <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
              <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha" />
              <feOffset />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" />
              <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.486275 0 0 0 0 0.737255 0 0 0 0 0.815686 0 0 0 0.47 0" />
              <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_551_5" />
              <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha" />
              <feOffset dy="1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" />
              <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.486275 0 0 0 0 0.737255 0 0 0 0 0.815686 0 0 0 0.28 0" />
              <feBlend mode="normal" in2="effect1_dropShadow_551_5" result="effect2_dropShadow_551_5" />
              <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha" />
              <feOffset dy="1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" />
              <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.486275 0 0 0 0 0.737255 0 0 0 0 0.815686 0 0 0 0.08 0" />
              <feBlend mode="normal" in2="effect2_dropShadow_551_5" result="effect3_dropShadow_551_5" />
              <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha" />
              <feOffset dy="2" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" />
              <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.486275 0 0 0 0 0.737255 0 0 0 0 0.815686 0 0 0 0.01 0" />
              <feBlend mode="normal" in2="effect3_dropShadow_551_5" result="effect4_dropShadow_551_5" />
              <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect4_dropShadow_551_5" result="shape" />
            </filter>
            <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_551_5" x1="13" y1="8" x2="13" y2="381" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
              <stop stop-color="#212529" />
              <stop offset="1" stop-color="#212529" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
        </svg>

      </div>

      <div class="right_wraper">

        <div class="card card_active">
          <div class="card_title">
            <h1>Card Title <span>|</span></h1>
            <p>Card Sub TItle</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card_content">
            <h3>Card inner content title</h3>

            <div class="card_key_points">
              <ul>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card_title">
            <h1>Card Title <span>|</span></h1>
            <p>Card Sub TItle</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card_content">
            <h3>Card inner content title</h3>

            <div class="card_key_points">
              <ul>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card_title">
            <h1>Card Title <span>|</span></h1>
            <p>Card Sub TItle</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card_content">
            <h3>Card inner content title</h3>

            <div class="card_key_points">
              <ul>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card_title">
            <h1>Card Title <span>|</span></h1>
            <p>Card Sub TItle</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card_content">
            <h3>Card inner content title</h3>

            <div class="card_key_points">
              <ul>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card_title">
            <h1>Card Title <span>|</span></h1>
            <p>Card Sub TItle</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card_content">
            <h3>Card inner content title</h3>

            <div class="card_key_points">
              <ul>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card_title">
            <h1>Card Title <span>|</span></h1>
            <p>Card Sub TItle</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card_content">
            <h3>Card inner content title</h3>

            <div class="card_key_points">
              <ul>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card_title">
            <h1>Card Title <span>|</span></h1>
            <p>Card Sub TItle</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card_content">
            <h3>Card inner content title</h3>

            <div class="card_key_points">
              <ul>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>

<!-- Jquery CDN -->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>


    <!-- UIkit JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.17.0/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.17.0/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Lenis JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@studio-freight/lenis@1.0.42/dist/lenis.min.js"></script>

    <!-- GSAP -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>





    <!-- GSAP Plugins-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/MotionPathPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Split Text -->
    <!-- Minified UMD bundle -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/split-type"></script>

    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>




Also toggleClass: "card_active" needs to be added as well

@Death-is-the-real-truth Yes working but not what I want the scaling is working but not in the sync of the Scroll also the opacity is not changing,
Here is the animation I want
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yZsK3-mGZ9tNLmKHzbhpYyesDnj4TfM3/view?usp=sharing

where do i add this toggle class

here is the Figma prototype link :
https://www.figma.com/proto/rhZU38YX13bj5MfdrdSZaw/My_Portfolio?node-id=575-302&t=Yswd1f0ECRitRg8U-0&scaling=min-zoom&content-scaling=fixed&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=573%3A3

This toggleClass: "card_active" has no effect.

just go the Codepen and try to edit there I have already added the Codepen link in the question but here is the link to the pen :
https://codepen.io/j_akki/pen/XWwwELP?editors=0010
